# Changing Key Of An Property in Json

Tags: c#, json, winforms, key

I'm trying to make a json editor(works with treeview) these days, i did changing value function, i can change some keys as well, but i cant set keys in objects.
I can set the value:

```
SetValue(ref JObject main,JToken token,JToken newValue) {
    //2nd argument is obj.SelectToken(node.Path)
     token.Replace(newValue);
}
```

I can also set some keys:

```
SetKey(ref JObject main,JToken token,string newKey) {
    //2nd argument is obj.SelectToken(node.Path)
    //However, if token is in object, it seys the key of object because parent is object
     (token.Parent as JProperty).Replace(newKey);
}
```

But how can i set the keys?
Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to pass the original root object by ref and you don't need the original root at all.  All you care about is the JToken and its parent.

In this case, you want to think of "replacement" as:

> - Add the old value by new key
> - Remove the old key/value pair

```
 public void SetKey(JObject parent, JToken token, string newKey) 
 {
    var tokenProp = token as JProperty;
    var oldKeyName = tokenProp.Name;
    parent[newKey] = tokenProp.Value;
    parent.Remove(oldKeyName);
}
```

We can assume that if you are replacing a key for a key value pair, that the object is a JProperty token.  In addition, if we are replacing keys, it is also safe to assume the parent is a JObject.  You can call it as such:

```
var json = "{ 'key1': 'val1' }";
JObject parsedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
SetKey(parsedObj, parsedObj.First, "key2");
```

Comment: Thats a nice solution =) But when i tried to print parent before, i got jproperty instead of object. How does parent works?

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz if you try to walk up the parent from the token, you may run into unexpected issues, although that technically should work as well.  That said, if you do, you'll most likely have to cast to `JObject`. However, in my approach, if I'm already walking down a JSON tree, I probably know both the current root object and the token that I am interested in.  It is easier to simply pass those in at that point than trying to reach up to the parent from the token.

Comment: Since parent is jproperty, currentObject.SelectToken(lastNode.GetNodePath()) is the jobject i am looking for. So the method is :                               void SetKey(this JObject @object,string oldKey,string newKey) {  JToken oldValue = obj[oldKey]; @object.Remove(oldKey); @object[newKey] = oldValue }

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I had to remove whitespaces from all properties within a JObject, but didn't want to use a helper function. With `using System.Linq`:

```cs
var descendants = jObject.Descendants().Where(attr => attr is JProperty && ((JProperty)attr).Name.Contains(" ")).ToList();
descendants.ForEach(attr => attr.Parent[((JProperty)attr).Name.Replace(" ", string.Empty)] = ((JProperty)attr).Value);
descendants.ForEach(attr => attr.Remove());
```